# tkinter Checkbutton widget returning wrong boolean value

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I have a simple GUI here that's suppose to return a boolean value depending on whether the check button is checked or not. I've set the boolean variable to False hence the empty check button. What I don't understand is that when I check the button, the function binded to that widget returns a False instead of True. Why is that?

Here's the code...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def getBool(event):
    print(boolvar.get())

root = Tk()

boolvar = BooleanVar()
boolvar.set(False)

cb = Checkbutton(root, text = "Check Me", variable = boolvar)
cb.bind("<Button-1>", getBool)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

when checking the empty button the function outputs...

```
False
```

Shouldn't it return `True` now that the button is checked?

Comment: I suspect that your binding is firing the moment the mouse is clicked - before the Checkbutton gets a chance to update its state.  Try using the Checkbutton's `command=` option, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boolean value is changed after the bind callback is made. To give you an example, check this out:

```
from tkinter import *

def getBool(event):
    print(boolvar.get())


root = Tk()

boolvar = BooleanVar()
boolvar.set(False)
boolvar.trace('w', lambda *_: print("The value was changed"))

cb = Checkbutton(root, text = "Check Me", variable = boolvar)
cb.bind("<Button-1>", getBool)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you presses the Checkbutton, the first output is `False` then it's `"The value was changed"`, which means that the value was changed after the `getBool` callback is completed.

What you should do is to use the `command` argument for the setting the callback, look:

```
from tkinter import *

def getBool(): # get rid of the event argument
    print(boolvar.get())


root = Tk()

boolvar = BooleanVar()
boolvar.set(False)
boolvar.trace('w', lambda *_: print("The value was changed"))

cb = Checkbutton(root, text = "Check Me", variable = boolvar, command = getBool)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The output is first `"The value was changed"` then `True`.

*For my examples, I used `boolvar.trace`, it runs the lambda callback when the boolean value changes (`'w'`)*

Comment: Okay I see, thanx. for the thorough explanation